# Print an empty square using an argument in Python

Tags: python, square

I want to draw the outer lines of a square. I am able to create a filled in square, using the shown code, however I am not sure how to make it empty on the inside.

This is what I have:

```
def square(size):
    for x in range(0, size):
        print("*  " * size)
square(5)
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

If numpy is an option, here is an approach with it:

```
import numpy as np
def square(size):
    square = np.ones((size, size), dtype='object')
    square[1:-1, 1:-1] = ' '
    square[square==1] = '*'
    print('\n'.join([' '.join([str(elem) for elem in row]) for row in square]))

square(15)
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
*                           *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Without numpy, you could use [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to achieve your goal

```
def square(size):
    for i in range(0, size):
        if i not in [0, size-1]:
            print('*'.ljust(size*2-2) + '*')
        else:
            print('* ' * size)
```

Comment: This will be great for when I am able to use numpy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of printing the rows one by one is intuitive and correct, but to leave the inner of the square empty you need to treat rows differently, depending on where they occur.
To be precise, you only need to print `"*"` `size` times at the first and last row, and rows in the middle you need to keep in mind that they only have `"*"` at the edges.

Your code becomes:

```py
def square(size):
    # first row (all need to be filled)
    print("*  " * size)
    # inner rows, we only print "*" at the start and at the end, the middle is empty
    for x in range(0, size-2):
        print("*  " + "   "*(size-2) + "*")
    # last row (all need to be filled)
    print("*  " * size)

square(5)
```

I would recommend only printing once and add separators (e.g. the whitespace between `"*"`) programmatically.

```py
def square(size):
    sep = "  "
    letter = "*"

    # keep track of what we want to print
    rows = []
    # first row
    rows.append([letter] * size)
    # middle rows
    for x in range(0, size-2):
        rows.append([letter] + [" "] * (size-2) + [letter])
    # last row
    rows.append([letter] * size)

    # join() lists with symbol and line separator
    print("\n".join([sep.join(row) for row in rows]))

square(5)
```